# Kohana 3 ORM Relationships Question

Tags: php, model-view-controller, orm, kohana

I've been through several sites (including this one), and unfortunately as a Kohana newbie I still can't get this to work. The data relationship is fairly simple, I have a company record, which should be linked to 1 status record and 1 type record. Of course there will be multiple companies in the table, but each company is only allowed to be linked to 1 of each (and must be).

What I have is:

```
class Model_Company extends ORM
{
    protected $_has_one = array(
        'companystatus' => array('model' => 'companystatus', 'foreign_key' => 'entryid'),
        'companytype' => array('model' => 'companytype', 'foreign_key' => 'entryid')
        ,
    );
}
```

Company Status Model:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct access allowed.');

class Model_CompanyStatus extends ORM
    {
        protected $_table_name = 'datadictionary';
        protected $_primary_key = 'entryid';

        protected $_has_many = array(
            'company' => array('foreign_key' => 'statusid')
            ,
        );
    }

?>
```

Company Type Model:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct access allowed.');

    class Model_CompanyType extends ORM
    {
        protected $_table_name = 'datadictionary';
        protected $_primary_key = 'entryid';

        protected $_has_many = array(
            'company' => array('foreign_key' => 'companytypeid')
            ,
        );
    }

?>
```

The companystatus and companytype models are mapped to a single table which has 2 fields, entryid and entryname. This table is called "datadictionary", and has the appropriate properties so that I don't have to use "id" as the record id field.

Now I load my Company record like this:

```
$company = ORM::factory('company')
    ->where('id', '=', 1)
    ->where('hasbeendeleted', '=', 0)
    ->find();
```

The problem is that I don't get anything back for the companystatus and companytype properties for the company, and when I do a $company->companystatus->find() I get the first record returned, which is weird. What am I missing?

Thanks!!

:-)

Edit:
For simplicity's sake the Companies table has the following fields:

```
ID (primary key) - auto inc int
CompanyName - varchar(255)
StatusID - int
CompanyTypeID - int
HasBeenDeleted - smallint (0 for false, 1 for true)
```

DataDictionary Table:

```
EntryID (primary key) - auto inc int
EntryName - nvarchar(255)
```

Example Company record:

```
ID: 1
CompanyName: TestCompany
StatusID: 1
CompanyTypeID: 3
HasBeenDeleted: 0
```

Example DataDictionary records:

```
EntryID: 1
EntryName: Active

EntryID: 2
EntryName: Inactive

EntryID: 3
EntryName: Customer

EntryID: 4
EntryName: Supplier
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things here I would try changing.

First of all, for readability, most people use underscores in foreign keys.  So instead of `entryid`, I'd recommend using `entry_id` (you'd have to make the change in both your database and your code).

In Kohana 3, declaring `'model' => 'companystatus'` in a `$has_one` array is redundant when the key is the same as the model name.  You can safely remove that part.

But really, that's all incidental to your problem, which exists somewhere between that last ORM call and your database.  (I'm assuming here that `hasbeendeleted` is a column in the `company` table, not either of the other two tables you mentioned.  Let me know if that's not the case.)

If you're doing a `->where('id', '=', 1)` together with a `->find()`, you're really expecting to return the one company record if it exists in the database.  I would recommend making a separate check for `hasbeendeleted`.

And speaking of which, instead of naming that variable `$companies`, it should really be singular (e.g. `$company`) since it will only hold one record.

And you can simplify `ORM::factory('company')->where('id', '=', 1)` to simply `ORM::factory('company', 1)`

If you *know* for sure that a company with a database ID of 1 exists, then the following code should return that record:

`$myCompany = ORM::factory('company', 1);`

Then you can do something like `if ( ! $myCompany->hasbeendeleted) ...`

That should help you a bit.  Post more details if you run into trouble.

Comment: Thanks for that, and from a cleanliness point of view your comments are excellent. The problem, however, is that I do not get a CompanyStatus or CompanyType record when setting up the relationship as my original post. That's my issue. I would like the Kohana ORM to take care of this for me, rather than doing 3 DB calls (company, then status and type records).

Comment: @Dominik Do you have `$_has_many` set  in your `Model_CompanyStatus` and `Model_CompanyType` to link them to `Model_Company`?  (I'm assuming you're trying to implement a one-to-many relationship between statuses/types and companies.)

Comment: Hi again (and thanks again for taking the time), yes I do have $_has_many in the Model_CompanyStatus and Model_CompanyType files. When I call the ORM method to get a single company, do I need to place a call to get the associated company type and status? I have tried $company->companystatus->find();, however this does not return the value based on the company record, it appears to just get the first record, or only displays the first record in the view.

Comment: @Dominik Hmmm...  I'd have to see your code (the variables, not necessarily any methods) for `Model_CompanyStatus` and `Model_CompanyType` to provide further help on this.  Can you add that to your question?  Also, please update any of the existing code there to reflect any changes that you may have made since posting this question.

Comment: @Dominik I'll also need a brief description of the salient parts of the three related database tables (at least table names, primary keys, and any other parts that you're trying to use, like `hasbeendeleted`).

Comment: No probs, I have edited the original post with those details. It's very, very simple at the moment, cut down so that I can test Kohana's viability in a pseudo-real way :-)

Comment: @Dominik This code works properly for me in Kohana 3.1 exactly as you have posted it.  Did you remember to enable (uncomment) the Database and ORM modules in `bootstrap.php`?  What is the output of `$this->response->body('<pre>'.print_r($companies, TRUE).'</pre>');` when added after that ORM line in your controller?

Comment: Damn, I still get nothing when I do a $company->companystatus in the view file. All other fields work, like $company->CompanyName, this returns the company name. I did the print_r as well, and got a lot of stuff back. The most relevant lines appear to be : [last_query] => SELECT `systemdatadictionary`.* FROM `systemdatadictionary` WHERE `systemdatadictionary`.`entryid` IS NULL LIMIT 1  - I am not sure why it says "IS NULL", when the company record definitely has a numeric value in it for statusid and companytypeid.

Comment: p.s. Both the Database and ORM lines are uncommented in bootstrap.php as well. If Kohana ORM doesn't work, at least not with this table structure, can you recommend an ORM framework that will work in conjunction with Kohana? Thanks!

Comment: @Dominik To be honest, it seems like you dove into the deep-end of the ORM "pool" without knowing how to swim -- you've started with many quirks that make your problems difficult to troubleshoot on a site like this.  I would recommend starting over and following the examples in the [ORM section of the Kohana User Guide](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/orm) *exactly*.  Once you have that working, modify it a bit at a time to meet your needs.  I'm not trying to be mean, but I've already put over an hour into helping you on this thread, and I'm out of time.  Best of luck!

Comment: @Dominik I will say, finally, that what you're trying to do can be easily accomplished using Kohana's built-in ORM module, so you're on the right track.  Also, you should try to follow common coding conventions (some of which I mentioned in my answer above) -- doing so will make it easier for other people online to help you troubleshoot your problems.